# Need to align four lines of display-style math

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, align

[image]

I want write this in LaTeX. especially  with the brace on the right-hand side, and the `=` signs aligned horizontally. so I used `align`..  This is how it looks like in the output:

[image]

I am so desperate right now. every single time, latex doesn't seem to work right and this digitalizing takes more time than it already takes. Here is my code and my packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
%\usepackage{subfig} %Um mehrere Grafiken via {subfigure} in ein eine {figure}-Umgebung zu tun
\usepackage{caption}
      \usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    g_1: \; \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}_1 + t\vec{a}\\
    g_2: \; \vec{r}(s) &= \vec{r}_2 + s\vec{v}\\
    \left \vec{a} \times \vec{b} &\neq 0\\\langle \vec{a} \; \vec{b} \; \overrightarrow{P_1P_2} \rangle &\neq 0 \right\} \Rightarrow (\textrm{windschief})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I also tested it with an array, but it didn't work, the equation signs weren't among themselves..

Comment: A quick observation: `\left \vec{a} ... \right\}` can't be correct. You probably intended `\left. ... \right\}`. (Note the "dot" immediately after `\left`.)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you use an `rcases` environment, provided by the mathtools package, for lines 3 and 4. A separate comment: use `\colon`, not `:`, in rows 1 and 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package last
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\begin{aligned}
    g_1\colon \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}_1 + t\vec{a}\\
    g_2\colon \vec{r}(s) &= \vec{r}_2 + s\vec{v}
   \end{aligned} \\
  &\begin{rcases}
     \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \neq 0\\
     \big\langle \vec{a\mathstrut}\,\vec{b\mathstrut}\,
          \overrightarrow{P_1P_2} \big\rangle \neq 0 
   \end{rcases}\Rightarrow (\text{windschief})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the material to the right of the curly brace on lines 3 and 4 should be typeset flush-right (also known as ragged-left), I suggest you employ an `array` environment instead of the `rcases` environment.

[image]

```
% preamble exactly the same as above
\begin{align*}
  &\begin{aligned}
    g_1\colon \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}_1 + t\vec{a}\\
    g_2\colon \vec{r}(s) &= \vec{r}_2 + s\vec{v}
   \end{aligned} \\
  &\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
   \kern-2\nulldelimiterspace % adjust spacing at left-hand edge
   \left.\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}r@{}}
     \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \neq 0\\
     \big\langle \vec{a\mathstrut}\,\vec{b\mathstrut}\,
          \overrightarrow{P_1P_2} \big\rangle \neq 0 
   \end{array}\right\}
   \Rightarrow (\text{windschief})
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest two other alignment possibilities.  Also, you might be interested by the `\vv`command, from the `esvect` package, which has nicer arrow tips, in my opinion (7 variants!), and manages indices with `\vv*`. I used it in the second code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp, helvet, old-arrows}
\usepackage[b]{esvect} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package last (exception: cleveref)

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    g_1\colon \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}_1 + t\vec{a} \\
    g_2\colon \vec{r}(s) &= \vec{r}_2 + s\vec{v} \\
  \begin{rcases}
     \begin{aligned}\vec{a} \times \vec{b} & \neq 0\\
     \big\langle \vec{a\mathstrut}\,\vec{b\mathstrut}\,
            \overrightarrow{P_1P_2} \big\rangle & \neq 0
\end{aligned}
   \end{rcases} & \Rightarrow (\text{windschief})
\end{align*}

\begin{gather*}
  \begin{aligned}
    g_1\colon \vv{r}(t) &= \vv*{r}{\!1} + t\vv{a}\\
    g_2\colon \vv{r}(s) &= \vv*{r}{\!2} + s\vv{v}
   \end{aligned} \\
  \begin{rcases}
     \begin{aligned}\vv{a} \times \vv{b} & \neq 0\\
     \bigl\langle \vv{a\vphantom{b}}\,\vv{b}\,
          \vv*{P_1P\,}{\mkern-5mu 2} \bigr\rangle & \neq 0
\end{aligned}
   \end{rcases}\Rightarrow (\text{windschief})
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! i used your solution. what does gather, aligned and rcases do? i dont know these, i use latex just since 4 weeks and i am still learning it

Comment: `gather` is for non-aligned multiline equations, each of them (or each group) being centred. `aligned` is to align  a group of lines within a main multiline equation, and `rcases` is like cases, but with a right brace on the right of the group.

Comment: @LillienSabrinaGluch Dear user according to my point of view you should take into account the ethic that is very important when writing in LaTeX. The very good Bernard and Mico gave you excellent answers.